# ObservableArray binding failing with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Depending on how I change the property in an object of an observableArray, the property value get updated or not in the HTML. I wish I could understand why...

I simplified my code as much as I could to show the difference:

- one that work: updating the whole object
- the other that Fails: updating only the method of that object

In both case I force the update with valueHasMutated.

http://jsfiddle.net/fCXAq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your val member needs to be an observable

http://jsfiddle.net/fCXAq/2/

Comment: Thanks. I now understand: a observableArray will get updated in the HTML only when it is an addition or removal of object (my working example). If need be to go in updating only its method (with no change to the full object) then those needs to be observed (the solution proposed for the non working example).